# PyQt QTreeWidget - SIGNAL 'clicked' from header

Tags: pyqt4, qtreewidget

Is it possible to make the header item of a QTreeWidget clickable ? ( what would be the syntax if it is ? )

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [`setClickable`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setClickable) method of the `QHeaderView` would be the way. You can get the `QHeaderView` by calling [`header()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#header) method of your `QTreeWidget`.